# Facelet labels in JSTL forEach loop are messed up after ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, facelets

I have a JSF page that renders a series of panel grids and the nested elements dynamically based on a member called **panels** in my managed bean where defines all meta-data (like each panel's title, columns, style, or each field's label, input type and mapping etc.). All panels and fields inside them are rendered via JSTL/core forEach loops. Now I want to render a panel based on user's selection.

The simplified page snippet looks like that:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="radio1" value="#{myBean.selectPanel}" layout="grid" columns="1">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option1" itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option2" itemValue="1" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.handleIt()}" process="@this" update="@form"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>

<c:forEach var="panel" items="#{myBean.panels}">
    <c:if test="#{not empty panel.render}">
        <h:panelGrid id="#{panel.name}">
            <c:forEach var="field" items="#{panel.fields}">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle[field.label]}" escape="false" for="#{field.name}"/>
                <!-- input fields like input box or dropdown list are ignored here -->
            </c:forEach>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Managed bean with dummy panels initialization

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean{
    private List<Panel> panels = new ArrayList<Panel>();

    public void initPanels() {
        Panel p;
        Field f;

        p = new Panel();
        //instantiate a Field by passing label and name
        f = new Field("panel1_label1", "panel1_field1");
        p.addField(f);
        panels.add(p);

        p = new Panel();
        f = new Field("panel2_label1", "panel2_field1");
        p.addField(f);
        panels.add(p);

        this.setSelectPanel(0);
    }
    ...
}
```

When the page is firstly loaded, everything looks fine, only selected panel is displayed. But when you select the radio button, it always showed the first panel label, however the corresponding input fields are always rendered correctly.

And if I added the "id" attribute to labels like that, then I saw the right id was assigned.

```
<h:outputLabel id="#{'lbl_'.concat(field.name)}" value="#{bundle[field.label]}" escape="false" for="#{field.name}"/>
```

the output html label will like:

```
<label id="myForm:lbl_panel2_field1" for="myForm:panel2_field1">Panel1 Field1 Label</label>
```

This meant TagHandler had used the right field data when UIViewRoot tree was built, and it's also proved when I debugged it (after *FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FacesContext, UIViewRoot)* is called). so my question is how could JSF use wrong field object at the time the label's "**value**" expression is evaluated when the view is being rendered?

The interesting thing is if I refresh this page, then the panel will be displayed correctly no matter which panel I choose.

BTW I am using Spring Web Flow + JSF (version 2.2.8).
Any explanation or help is appreciated.

Comment: The jst tags are not re-evaluated after an ajax call. (or is that not your problem?)

Comment: @Kukeltje, I can see the "value" is re-evaluated when I added debug print, but by using the wrong field object.

Comment: There is no value on the jstl tag, it is on the jsf tag. So the jstl tags are not re-evaluated. The field tags are the ones that were there when the page was created. So what is 'wrong' in there? What is field is used? What did you expect? What does the listener do? Please create an [mcve] and be more clear on the problem. The fact that it 'works' if you reload the page is because the view is rebuild then.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my previous comment. I modified my post a bit to be clearer. So basically the "value" I meaned is the jsf outputLabel, and it's re-evaluated but referenced to wrong "field" object. And the panels object(and their associated fields) is the member of managed bean. The listener do nothing but set the render value of each panel. So the problem is when "id" of <h:outputLabel> is evaluated correctly, but not the "value" of <h:outputLabel>.

Comment: I understood, but you need to investigate yourself what 'wrong' means. We don't have an [mcve]